# I have two array. I want to compare both of them in a way that I can get the nearest value from the other array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So sorry for not being specific. here i have two array. what i want to take each element or each index value from Array B and then compare that value or the element with the Array A value for instance if B[0] = 1 and if Array A contains 1 then I want to create a new array C which contains the number of time 1 is present in that array  i.e array A. But If 1 doesn't exist in Array A then we should see for the closest number in array A i.e In array A 0 and 10 are the closest number to 1.

so here what the answer should look like

```
A = [0,10,20,30,40,50]

B = [1,8,7,8,2,3,4,11,14,16,17,24,29,31,39,35,39,30,44,46,45,45,48]

B[0] = 1 then comparing it to A then 0 and 10 is the closest value so

0 + 10 / 2 = 5 just to compare difference

now 1 < 5

    so we should keep 1 = 0 similarly

    B[1] = 8

    but here 8 > 5 

    so 8 = 10

the new array should be like this

A = [0,10,20,30,40,50]

B = [1,8,7,8,2,3,4,11,14,16,17,24,29,31,39,35,39,30,44,46,45,45,48]

Answer C = [4 , 5 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 2 ]

so  C[0] is for range 1 to 5 which is 4 times;
    C[1] is for range 6 to 15 which is 5 times;
    C[2] is for range 16 to 25 which is 3 times;
    C[3] is for range 26 to 35 which is 4 times;
    C[4] is for range 36 to 45  which is 4 times;
    C[5] is for range 46 to 55 which is 2 times;
```

I Still Dont think I have Cleared my question properly Still i hope you all 
can understand actually these are not array but i had to make them array as I have three values rangeFrom = 0 , rangeTo = 50 and LeastCount =10; so by this I created array A. So by Values of array A and C i want to plot a graph

Comment: have you switched a and b? please add the wanted result and your try.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Those are neither arrays nor objects

Comment: I think you're answer needs to be rewritten so that its less mental calories to try and answer. Perhaps divide into logical paragraphs and explain a bit more about what you want. For instance is your result going to be an array? when you are referencing A =6, B=10 etc.. its open to interpretation what you mean, try and describe more definitively

Comment: i have edited my question so you all can have better understanding of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the values of `b` by finding their corresponding value of `a`.

```js
const
    convert = (a, b) => b.map(v => a.find((b, i, { [i + 1]: a, length }) => 
        i + 1 === length ||
        v - a <= b - v
    )),
    a = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    b = [1, 8, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 11, 14, 16, 17, 24, 29, 31, 39, 35, 39, 30, 44, 46, 45, 45, 48],
    c = [-1, -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1],
    d = [-1, -0.9, -0.54, -0.24, -0.12, 0, 0.21, 0.14, 0.3, 0.81, 0.1, -0.1, -0.19, -0.54, -0.24, -0.13, 0, 0.21, 0.14, 0.36, 0.80, 0.1];

console.log(...b);
console.log(...convert(a, b));
console.log('');
console.log(...d);
console.log(...convert(c, d));
console.log(...[-1, -1, -0.6, -0.2, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0, 0, -0.2, -0.6, 0.2, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0]);
```

Comment: Hi this works but what if I have an array with very small numbers Like in decimal point would it work for that to

Comment: @SAAGARJHA, just try it, or add the arrays to the question with the wanted result.

Comment: for example if array A = [-1, -0.8 ,-0.6 ,-0.4 ,-0.2, 0 , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 , 0.8 , 1]  And array B =  [-1, -0.9 ,-0.54 ,-0.24 ,-0.12, 0 , 0.21, 0.14, 0.3 , 0.81 , 0.1, -0.1, -0.19 ,-0.54 ,-0.24 ,-0.13, 0 , 0.21, 0.14, 0.36 , 0.80 , 0.1]

Comment: please add the other array and wanted values.

Comment: for example if array A = [-1, -0.8 ,-0.6 ,-0.4 ,-0.2, 0 , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 , 0.8 , 1]  And array B =  [-1 , -0.9 , -0.54  , -0.24  , -0.12 ,  0  ,  0.21 ,  0.14 ,  0.3  , 0.81 ,  0.1 ,  -0.1 , -0.19 , -0.54 , -0.24 , -0.13 , 0 , 0.21 , 0.14 ,  0.36 , 0.80 , 0.1]  so the answer should be some thing like this C=[-1, -1 , -0.6 , -0.2 , -0.2 , 0 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.8 , 0 , 0 , -0.2 ,- 0.6 , 0.2 , -0.2 , 0 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.8 , 0 ] Still thanks for your help

Comment: you have two value who are different than my a calculations, for the last numbers. 1. `-0.1` yields `-0.2` istead of your `0` and `0.36` yields `0.4` instead of your `0.2`. the actual rule take the smaller value for same delta and theke the value with the smallest delta works with my code. do you like to get a different resutl and what is the rule behind?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake form my end your solution work fine. thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the closest number in the second array for each number in the first array and insert it into a new array c, try this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  let diff = (a[i] - b[0]);
  if (diff < 0) diff *= -1;
  let tmp = 0;
    for (let j = 1; j < b.length; j++) {
    tmp = a[i] - b[j];
    if (tmp < 0) tmp *= -1;
    if (tmp < diff) diff = tmp;
  }
  c[i] = diff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lwhf536m/10/